# Flutter Text: number is displayed inside a circle

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'll give a very simple example of my problem:

```
int myNumber = 1;
Text(
    "This is my number: ($myNumber)",            
),
```

Expected behaviour from Text:

> This is my number: (1)

But I get:

> This is my number: ①

What causes this and what's the best way to avoid it?

Comment: Does that really give you a circle around the number or, as I would expect, a 1 inside a pair of parentheses?

Comment: Something strange. Update your question with `flutter doctor` output

Answer (score 2):

You should remove '( )' wrapped over `myNumber` check this,

```
int myNumber = 1;
Text(
    "This is my number: $myNumber",            
),
```

Comment: Excuse me, I made a mistake in the question. The goal is to display the number between braces, I added this information to the question. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
int myNumber = 1;
Text(
    "This is my number: ($myNumber)",            
),
```

its working fine check your code .

[image: code]

output

[image]